# Оператор LIKE SQL Не распознает регистр символов в строке

Tags: php, sql

Вопрос такой, нужно написать систему скидочных купонов для магазина, сделал для начала простую систему, форму с текстовым полем и кнопкой, написал запрос к БД, все работает но результат возвращается вне зависимости от регистра, т.е. если написать QQQqqq и QQQQQQ, это распознается одинаково, если написать QQQqqq1 то уже результата не будет. Необходимо учитывать регистр. Код ниже:

```
public static function checkDiscount($query)
    {
        $db = Db::getConnection();

        $sql = 'SELECT id FROM discount_code WHERE name LIKE :name';

        $result = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindParam(':name', $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->execute();

        $code = $result->fetch();
        if ($code) {
            return $code['id'];
        }
        return false;
    }
```

замена `LIKE` на `=` не меняет результат.

Comment: кодировка регистронезависимая. Запросы тут не помогут, а вот смена кодировки поможет. Я про базу данных

Comment: @ArchDemon Изменил кодировку с utf8_general_ci на cp1251_general_cs, не знаю на сколько верная она, но все стало работать как нужно , спасибо, я думал запрос как то не правильно писал, даже не думал про кодировку

Comment: зачем было менять с utf на cp1251 то? надо было `utf8_general_cs` поставить. А если регистр нужен был только для данного поискового запроса, то решалось это директивой `collate`

Comment: @teran У меня в Phpmyadmin есть только utf8_generacal_ci

Comment: А атрибут BINARY вам о чем-нибудь говорит?

Comment: @sepgg нет, поставил данный атрибут в таблице , выбрал utf8_generacal_ci и теперь все работает как нужно. Нужно изучить подробнее что это изменяет.

Comment: Ну если уж очень коротко, то он как раз делает поле регистрозависимым